# How to map Value Object that is stored in separate table in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have two tables **Order**, **OrderStatus** . **Order** has *OrderId* (pk), *OrderStatusId* (fk) and so on...
 **OrderStatus** has two columns *OrderStatusId* (pk) and *StatuCcode*. The tables are normalised so that there is a proper foreign key constraint on OrderStatusId column. However to me OrderStatus is just a value object all I will ever use it for is to read the **description** only. Can I keep the data model as it is now and map **Orderstatus**  as value object in NHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were a value object, it wouldn't have an Id.

It's an entity, map it as such.

Comment: So In essence any thing that has Id is an Entity? The only reason why this other table was created was for enforcing foreign key contstraint on column OrderStatusId of table Order so that it doesn't allow any value other than one of those in OderStatus table.

Comment: @Suman: In that case, I suggest you remove the table and replace it with an enum.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon Yes but correct me if im wrong, value objects can still have a persistent identity just for the db? And OrderStatus in Sumans context looks like a value object not an entity. I am still not 100% sure what to do when wanting to save a value object into a separate table also.

Comment: @geepie: I believe there might be a mismatch between what you consider a value object and what NH considers a value object. One of the *definitions* of a value object is that it doesn't have an identity; instead, equality is defined by its properties.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon ok thanks for that. Im looking at it from a more DDD perspective. So what happens if you want to map a ddd value object into a separate table? Would you not use the component map?

Comment: @geepie: Value objects are not stored on their own. That would be just like having a table for System.Int32

Comment: geepie.. I ended up mapping all of them as Entities.